# What to look for digiscoping on a tight budget?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, astrophotography

I own a cheap telescope. What should I look for in a cheap used camera for a first digiscoping experience? I'm looking to spend a very minimal amount of money — hopefully under $100.

Comment: I edited my question. Is that now on-topic enough?

Answer (score -2):

Yes there is. If you look at ebay there are for example canon 350d bodies availible from around $40. That is an resonable camera to start out with. A slightly newer model might be a bit better thou as the 350d lacks live view which helps manual focusing.

Comment: Please try to resist the temptation to answer off-topic questions - it gives people the [unfortunately now correct] impression they can ask anything & get an answer.